# Testing privileges for PHP script's MySQL user

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am making a website that I expect to be hosted on several servers. I want to be able to check to make sure the MySQL user that has been created on those servers has sufficient privileges so that I can give a clear error if one of the privileges that the MySQL user requires is missing.
I found the MySQL command `SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER` but its output looks like it would require a bunch of work to parse.

Is there a better way to verify that the MySQL user has sufficient permissions?

Comment: Doesn't necessarily need to be in PHP. If there is a good solution with MySQL that is fine too, just not in Perl or Python or something preferably.

Answer (score 1):

Hi try using the select statement below instead of SHOW GRANTS.

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.user WHERE USER LIKE 'root';
```

Comment: this can be done if the user has an access to the mysql database.

Comment: Sorry, is it possible to get privilege information like that but just for one table as that command does not give any info about database level privileges

Comment: there's multiple tables in `mysql.*` that contain the global-, db-, and user-level privileges. you'll have to query them all to see what a user's REALLY got granted to them.